# How to make a phase shifter?

Tags: physical-design, phase-shift

I've gotten interested in beam-forming via a phased antenna array. I read a few articles/tutorials and they have very  nice diagrams of antenna arrays and how the antennas interact to behind each antenna is the key piece: A phase shifter. And yet when searching for it it seems like more of a theoretical device rather than a physical one-yet really phased antenna arrays exist. What is it exactly? Is it something so simple it's just assumed I know what it is?

**What, physically, is a phase shifter?**

Comment: The parts needed to shift phase depend on the base frequency.

Comment: Different lengths of coax work nicely as delay lines and, of course, a delay line can also be regarded as a phase shifter. So, pick the length of cable you need to produce a delay that corresponds to the correct phase shift at the frequency in question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on the frequency at which you want to use your phase array antenna how you would implement the phase shifting. Possible solutions are:

- separate receivers/transmitters per antenna or set of antennas, this phase shift can be implemented in baseband or at the LO signal
- a shorter or longer transmission line to the antennas
- RC filters and/or polyphase filters
- some form of delay line

Note that usually a phase array antenna is used for a certain narrow band so the phase shift only has to be predictable at that particular frequency band. So in practice the phase shift is simply a time delay of the signal.

There might be more that I can't think of now.