# How to determine length of coax to get a certain delay?

Tags: cables, phase-shift

This is a follow-up to [How to make a phase shifter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197818/how-to-make-a-phase-shifter), it seems one answer is to simply have different lengths of coax going to each antenna. However, how do I calculate the difference in length given the desired phase and frequency? My first assumption was that the signal should move at the speed of light, and so the calculation would be:

wavelength * (phase shift in degrees/360)

But then I remembered reading somewhere that a signal does not move at the speed of light through regular cable, but rather a fraction slower (2/3? 3/4?). Do I need to take the material the cable is made with into account?

Edit: To be clear, I'm hoping for a direct equation I can use to determine how to cut the length of cable in front of me.

Comment: @Andyaka done, if 7 years belated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signal does indeed move at the speed of light **for that medium**, which is usually some form of plastic insulating the coax.

Most solid plastics have a dielectric constant of a little more than 2, so their speed of light tends to be around the 0.65c range. Foamed dielectrics have a lower dielectric constant, so support faster signals.

To a good first approximation, you can use the formula

length = wavelength(in cable) * (phase shift in degrees/360),

where the wavelength(in cable) = 0.65c/frequency = 0.65wavelength(in air)

If you want more accuracy than that approximate 0.65 figure, then look up the data sheet for the speed of signals in your specific type of cable.

As the impedance of the cable depends on the sqrt(ratio) of L and C per unit length, and the speed depends on the sqrt(product) of L and C, the speed and the impedance are not directly related.

Comment: I think some data sheets call it the "velocity factor" but it's the same thing

Comment: What's L and C? Is C capacitence?

Comment: @shelvacu L is inductance, C is capacitance.

Comment: @shelvacu L is inductance per unit length, C is capacitance per unit length. When the cable is loaded with plastic, the C increases, but the L does not, so speed and impedance change from those in the same size air-spaced cable. An air-spaced cable would shift signals at the speed of light c. I've added the formulae to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Velocity factor is the proportion of c (speed of light) that a signal travels at in a cable: -

VF = \$\dfrac{1}{c\sqrt{LC}}\$

Where L and C are the distributed inductance and capacitance per metre length of the cable. Little "c" is the speed of light.

You can use \$\epsilon_R\$ as well because \$\mu_R\$ can be assumed to be unity: -

VF = \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_R}}\$

So (with the assumption that VF = 1) if you have a piece of coax that is 7.5m long and you feed it with a 10 MHz sinewave, the delay (phase shift) will be 90 degrees. If it's 15m long then the delay will be 180 degrees. A 30m length will look like the same phase as the original sinewave expect it will be lagging by one full wavelength.

If VF = 0.6667 (for example) the signal takes longer to travel a fixed distance than the speed of light hence, to obtain a 90 degree phase shift at 10MHz requires a length of cable that is 0.667 x 7.5m = 5m.

If all you can find is the characteristic impedance and capacitance per unit length you can also calculate VF like this: -

VF = \$\dfrac{1}{C\cdot Z_0}\$ because \$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$